# Firebase Conditional list data retrieval android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebaseui

I have below table rule in my `firebase database`

```
"tests": {
  "$user_id": {
    ".read": "$user_id===auth.uid",
    ".write": "$user_id===auth.uid",

    "$testId": {
      "duration": {
        ".validate": "newData.val().length>1"
      },
      "date": {
        ".validate": "newData.val().length>1"
      },
      "status": {
        ".validate": "newData.val()==='Pending' || newData.val()==='Completed'"
      }
    }
  }
},
```

Basically `tests` table will have 2 status, `pending` and `completed` and user will have 2 buttons in application for respective status of the `test`.

I have below `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter` to list the data.

```
final DatabaseReference testsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.TEST_TABLE).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Tests, TestListHolder > (
  Tests.class,
  R.layout.test_list_card,
  TestListHolder.class,
  testsRef
) {
  @Override
  protected void populateViewHolder(final TestListHolder viewHolder, final Tests model, final int position) {
      testsRef.child(adapter.getRef(position).getKey()).orderByChild("status")
      .equalTo(viewType).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
      @Override
      public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        //fill the view data
      }

      @Override
      public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
      }
    });

  }
};
```

So whenever presses `Pending` or `Completed` button, I will be passing `viewType` value as `Pending`/`Completed` respectively. But the above `orderByChild` isn't working and everytime all the data will be fetched in **both the views** and I believe proper reference of database is not fetched. Could someone help me to achieve this?

Here is the sample data if anyone insist:

```
"jxW41BgS12edasWtUkZA2G0eLhf2" : { //logged in user id
    "-KfFFioKvMDlAyqw43Yb" : { //testid
      "duration" : 4,
      "date" : 1489552731888,
      "status" : "Completed"
    },
    "-KfFGqIdenjwNdfs232EQ" : {//testid
      "duration" : 5,
      "date" : 1489552731888,
      "status" : "Pending",
    }
  }
```

Comment: Attaching a new listener to the same database location inside `populateViewHolder()` sounds wrong to be honest. It means that you'll be creating additional listeners all the time that you're not managing. All the data you need is already being loaded with the initial `testsRef` as far as I can see.

Comment: Aside from that: if you set a breakpoint in `populateViewHolder()`, does it eve get hit? If your `populateViewHolder()` is being triggered, you should be able to reproduce the problem with just the query. If `populateViewHolder()` doesn't get triggered, the second query is irrelevant to the problem.

Comment: It gets hit in `populateViewHolder()` and data gets loaded successfully. But all the data gets loaded without considering the condition.. @FrankvanPuffelen would you please suggest any better ways to do this?? Am frankly out of ideas.. :(

Comment: I still don't understand what you're trying to do. Are you simply trying to show a list of the tests that are (e.g.) pending in a recycler view?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen.. Exactly.. I am having same `activity` to display this list. It will be displayed in the same `recyclerview` present in that activity. The only thing am doing is segregating the data to be displayed. If user navigates to that view after clicking pending button from previous screen, then am supposed to display `pending` data and if he navigates after clicking completed button, then display `completed` data.. Hope its clear..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display only the pending tests:

```
DatabaseReference testsRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(Constants.TEST_TABLE).child(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());
Query pendingTestsQuery = testsRef.orderByChild("status").equalTo(viewType);
FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter <Tests, TestListHolder > (
  Tests.class,
  R.layout.test_list_card,
  TestListHolder.class,
  pendingTestsQuery
) {
  @Override
  protected void populateViewHolder(final TestListHolder viewHolder, final Tests model, final int position) {
      // TODO: display model in the viewHolder

  }
};
```

Comment: That's it buddy.. I wasn't aware that `Query` can be used instead of `DatabaseReference` inside `FirebaseRecyclerAdapter`. This worked well.. But I have one small doubt. Without attaching listener to this reference, how will these views gets updated?

Comment: The Firebase Adapters can be constructed with a DatabaseReference or a Query. It internally keeps a listener on that Query/Reference. See https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/master/database/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/database/FirebaseRecyclerAdapter.java#L78

Comment: Great work Frank... :) Am just in love with firebase.. :) Bdw.. I have some queries or better to say kind of review.. I wanted to know if am doing it right.. It would be great if you look into those.. I cannot post it here.. Shall I post it in **[Code Review Site](http://codereview.stackexchange.com)**